# Check concurrent connections per user on OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on a dedicated server and I want to know how many connections each user has open with the server.

To test, I made it so im the only one that can login, and then opened two connections from my pc with `openvpn config.ovpn`, they both connect fine and show *Initialization Sequence Completed*.

The server is started with the `--management` option so I tried to check there with `nc localhost PORT` and ran the load-stats command, it shows this:

```
load-stats
SUCCESS: nclients=1,bytesin=69908,bytesout=86912
```

Also tried `cat /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log` which shows:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Nov 14 17:33:19 2014
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
client1,111.222.333.444:51154,6770,7882,Fri Nov 14 17:32:32 2014
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.8.0.6,client1,111.222.333.444:51154,Fri Nov 14 17:32:35 2014
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

I can see how many clients are connected but not how many concurrent connections each one has, how can I check that?

Comment: What are you using for AAA ?

Comment: @Iain I am not using openvpn_as which does show each concurrent connection, I am using the community edition and no admin panel, I just login the clients using certificates created with easyrsa3.

Comment: @Zoredache I am connecting the same user twice. I am pretty sure both connections are working since I get two tun interfaces created, and using curl --interface tunX http://icanhazip.com both interfaces show the openvpn server ip.

Comment: @Zoredache Connecting two devices to openvpn using the same user is unusual? When the second device connects openvpn shows CLIENT:ESTABLISHED,2 - CLIENT:ENV,n_clients=1, CID is new but nclients stays at 1. Config contains duplicate-cn option.

Comment: @Zoredache Not seeing the error on any log or management session. But anyway I want to know how many concurrent connections an user has, not how to allow them.

Comment: @Zoredache I said I have the option, and I can have as many connections from the same user as I want and they all seem to work fine simultaneously (tried up to 10). But on the server side, i only see 1 client, not the X conections that client has. OpenVPN_AS web GUI does show all the concurrent connection from the same user/client, but I can't use that because it only allows 2 concurrent connections per user. So I am using the community edition.

Comment: `@Zoredache I said I have the option,` my mistake. I didn't notice you saying that.